# Mock Get override method make another test fail in xUnit.NET

Tags: moq, xunit.net

I have two tests using xUnit framework:

```
private IRepo myRepo;

public MyTests() { myRepo = Mock.Of<IRepo>(); ... }

[Fact]
public async void NoTenantTest()
{
  var validJson = GetValidJson();
  Mock.Get(myRepo).Setup(t => t.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(null as MyObject));
  var request = TestFactory.CreateHttpRequest(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "tenant", "abc" } }, "https://test.com", validJson);
  var ex = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => myAzureFunc.Run(request, mLog, mCtx));
  Assert.Equal("FindByIdAsync(abc) returned null", ex.Message, true);
}

[Fact]
public async void NoCompanyTest()
{
  var validJson = GetValidJson();
  Mock.Get(myRepo).Setup(t => t.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(new MyObject()));

 ...
 Mock.Get(myManager).Setup(w => w.GetIdAsync(It.IsAny<MyObject>()).Returns(Task.FromResult(null as string));

  var request = TestFactory.CreateHttpRequest(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "tenant", "abc" } }, "https://test.com", validJson);
  var ex = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => mPaymentWebhook.Run(request, mLog, mCtx));
  Assert.Equal("No item found for abc", ex.Message, true);
}
```

seems that xUnit executes tests in alphabetical order. And somehow the `Setup` from `Mock.Get(myRepo)` is not overriden and then `NoTenantTest` fails (I get another error message)

How to create new instance of IRepo object in order to avoid my situation ?

If I execute separately the tests, it works, if I run all, then fails.

Comment: xUnit runs tests in _random_ order, not alphabetic. It also creates a Fresh Fixture every time it runs, so the Mock object made in your ctor is made every time. You need to [opt into sharing via its Fixtures mechanism](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context) to _not_ get this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create them (mock) in the separate test methods and not as a shared resource initialized in the constructor.

Also if the tests are asynchronous, use `async Task` instead of `async void`

```
[Fact]
public async Task NoTenantTest() {
    var validJson = GetValidJson();
    IRepo myRepo = Mock.Of<IRepo>();
    Mock.Get(myRepo)
        .Setup(t => t.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(null as MyObject));
    var request = TestFactory.CreateHttpRequest(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "tenant", "abc" } }, "https://test.com", validJson);
    var ex = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => myAzureFunc.Run(request, mLog, mCtx));
    Assert.Equal("FindByIdAsync(abc) returned null", ex.Message, true);
}

[Fact]
public async Task NoCompanyTest() {
    var validJson = GetValidJson();
    IRepo myRepo = Mock.Of<IRepo>();
    Mock.Get(myRepo)
        .Setup(t => t.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(new MyObject()));

    ...
    Mock.Get(myManager)
        .Setup(w => w.GetIdAsync(It.IsAny<MyObject>())
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(null as string));

    var request = TestFactory.CreateHttpRequest(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "tenant", "abc" } }, "https://test.com", validJson);
    var ex = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => mPaymentWebhook.Run(request, mLog, mCtx));
    Assert.Equal("No item found for abc", ex.Message, true);
}
```